# Can a successful grant application be considered a publication in academia?

Tags: publications, funding, application

I have spent most of my professional life writing proposals for improving the living and studying conditions of the constituents I served (community members, students, curricula and higher education institutions). Well, after 25 years serving as a teacher, professor, dean, and chancellor I find myself looking for a job in academia as an education professor and my publication count is extremely low compared to the number of successful grant proposals that I have in my credentials.

**Can I count successful grant proposals, which actually changed the lives of thousands of people, as part of my publication or research record?**

Comment: A grant proposal is not a publication, because...well, because it is not published.  Whether a proposal is part of your research record may depend on what kind of grant it is and on your field.  In the branches of academia I'm familiar with, grant proposals go hand in hand with research, and a successful grant proposal is both a recognition of past research successes and a promise to undertake future research.  If your funded grants were for something other than research, could you please provide some further information about them?

Comment: Thank you Pete, the proposals and the projects created by those requests provided free educational services to public school students & teachers at the community level (private foundations & government agencies: Echoing Green Foundation, NEA, NEH), tutorial services to low level college students (USDE: Title V), science & language labs at higher education institutions (USDE: Title V). I have evidence of the grant approvals (award letters) and the successful projects' implementation (final reports and external evaluations).

Comment: I dont think anyone is arguing that what you have done has not had an impact or been of great worth, but that has nothing to do with if it is a "Publication" or not.  You state yourself it is a grant proposal.  If you asked, "Does a detailed report to the government on the success of a grant proposal count as a Publication" , it would be a different conversation

Comment: @PeteL.Clark You should expand this into a full answer.

Comment: No. Publications are about *results* while grant applications are about *expected results*.

Comment: Hi Pete, I agree with xLeitix, can you expand on your answer. Lets consider all the reports for these projects instead of the grant proposals, are we talking valid publications or at least valid documents that will fulfill the publication requirements for an Associate Professor in a School of Education?

Comment: @Luis: With apologies to Hubert Farnsworth: "Please, Luis! I don't know about education. I'm a professor!"  In all seriousness I have the vague feeling that my own academic experiences (in mathematics departments) will not transfer over well to your situation, so I don't want to leave an inapplicable answer.

Answer (score 31):

No.  Count them as part of your funding record.

Based on what you have said of your record, people will expect you to look for a job in research administration.  E.G. Vice President of Research, or Director of Research Facilities.

If you want to go back to teaching, the usual strategy I hear about in the news is to get an admin/leadership job and then demote yourself after a few years.

Answer (score 12):

Successful grant proposals should certainly be part of your CV as you search for a teaching job. **However, grants are NOT considered publications in academia.** For example, see [this CV](http://racc.edu/Faculty/lawlor/pdf/vita.pdf), where a friend of mine details his publications, and follows that with a section of successful grant proposals. This is the correct way to present them on your CV.

You may want to put the grants front and center on your CV, to highlight your expertise at bringing in funding, which few institutions will count as a negative!  You may also want to follow @guest's advice and look for a job in research/leadership/administration, and then demote yourself to a teaching position after a few years.

Answer (score 5):

To add to @guest's answer: employers will generally not count them as publications, but that does not mean you cannot publish them.  There is a growing trend of "publishing" grant proposals, usually by non-traditional means.  For instance, I have put some of mine on [Figshare](http://figshare.com/):

- [Wave Propagation for Next-Generation Supercomputers](http://dx.doi.org/10.6084/m9.figshare.639182)
- [Positive Numerical Solution of Differential Equations](http://dx.doi.org/10.6084/m9.figshare.639184)
- [High Performance Computing and High-Level Programming Concepts for Hyperbolic PDE Codes](http://dx.doi.org/10.6084/m9.figshare.639183)

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. The question is about whether grant applications count as publications, not about what steps can be taken to make one's grant applications public.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it is kind of reviewed and you definitely can mention successful grant applications on your CV. However they are normally not counted as publications. Usually it is possible to have publications describing scientific results obtained using the grant.